# Split collections of interfaces implementing a common interface by interface, not by implementations

Tags: c#, linq, generics, interface

Let's say that I have the following three interfaces:

```
IAnimal
IDog:IAnimal
ICat:IAnimal
```

And 3 classes:

```
Beagle: IDog
BullDog: IDog
Persian: ICat
```

I have 2 Persian, 1 BullDog, and 5 Beagles inside a list of IAnimal.
How can I split the `List<IAnimal>` into `List<IDog>` and `List<ICat>`.
So that I can have

```
List<IDog> Dogs //with 1 BullDog, and 5 Beagles inside
List<ICat> Cats //with 2 Persians inside?
```

I want to create two read-only properties getting from the `List<IAnimal> Animals`.
i.e.

```
List<IDog> Dogs => Animals.Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(BullDog) || x.GetType() == typeof(Beagle)).ToList()
```

However, this requires me to list out all implementation classes.
Is there a way to do this by using the interface in the where clause?
i.e.

```
List<IDog> Dogs => Animals.Where(x => x.IsIDog).ToList()
```

Comment: `OfType` works with interfaces, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a LINQ method specifically made for this operation - [`OfType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=net-5.0). It only keeps objects that are assignable to the specified type, so you can do:

```
List<IDog> dogs => Animals.OfType<IDog>().ToList();
List<ICat> cats => Animals.OfType<ICat>().ToList();
```